# Purpose of Redshift Enhanced VPC routing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

What is the purpose of Enhanced VPC routing for Redshift ?

I've read the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-routing.html
but it it not clear to me.

When you create a redshift cluster, the leader node resides in a VPC / subnet.
Hence it will always use VPC routing, Security groups etc to route requests right ?
How come that redshift wouldn't use VPC traffic when performing "COPY" commands ?

Comment: Right there in the link: "If enhanced VPC routing is not enabled, Amazon Redshift routes traffic through the internet, including traffic to other services within the AWS network.". So no, it will not always use VPC routing.

Comment: That's what I don't understand.

Comment: You'll need to clarify the question.

Comment: How can a node (so basically an EC2 instance) escape the VPC traffic ? If I launch it in a private subnet, how can it access internet ?

Comment: If you launch it in a subnet with no route to the internet and with Enhanced VPC routing disabled, it will not work at all.

Comment: mmm ok, what I don't understand is what enhanced VPC routing does. Let's say I run a "COPY" command to load data from an S3 bucket. If I want to force the traffic to stay on the AWS network I have to configure a VPC endpoint (gateway endpoint for S3 for instance). So the fact that the traffic won't use the public internet depends on VPC endpoints (and routing / SG config). Hence, why do we have to explicitly enable "Enhanced VPC routing". What's the effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhanced VPC routing forces the traffic to go through your VPC.

With it disabled, even if your cluster is in a VPC, it will route traffic via the public Internet instead of going through the VPC.

This is because it uses an "internal" network interface that's outside of the VPC, regardless of whether or not the cluster itself is in a VPC.

Here's a relevant excerpt from the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-enhanced-vpc-routing/):

> In Amazon Redshift, network traffic created by COPY, UNLOAD, and Amazon Redshift Spectrum flow through a network interface. This network interface is internal to the Amazon Redshift cluster, and is located outside of your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC). By default, the network traffic is then routed through the public internet to reach its destination.

> However, when you enable Amazon Redshift enhanced VPC routing, Amazon Redshift routes the network traffic through a VPC instead. Amazon Redshift enhanced VPC routing uses an available routing option, prioritizing the most specific route for network traffic. The VPC endpoint is prioritized as the first route priority. If a VPC endpoint is unavailable, Amazon Redshift routes the network traffic through an internet gateway, NAT instance, or NAT gateway.

Comment: Thank you. The fact that the traffic is going to stay on AWS internal network depends on networking configuration (setting up VPC endpoints). So this is external to redshift nodes right ? Hence my question is why is it needed to tell Redshift something that is external to it (using VPC endpoints doesn't require any configuration on the nodes from my understanding) ?

Comment: "The fact that the traffic is going to stay on AWS internal network depends on networking configuration (setting up VPC endpoints)" No. It depends on the Enhanced VPC routing being enabled. If it's disabled, Redshift will ignore the VPC endpoints and will use the public internet.

Comment: What sounds weird:
"Redshift will ignore the VPC endpoints".  
Gateway endpoints are just prefix list (so entries) in the subnet route table.

So not enabling "enhanced VPC routing" is forcing the redshift nodes not 
to respect the route table of the subnet ?

Comment: "they don't override the public internet-facing endpoints. They're under a separate URL address".
I don't understand that part sorry.
If a create a gateway endpoint for S3, it will add the different public IP addresses of the S3 service inside my Route table.
So whatever the URLs used by resources in that subnet, any communication with S3 will use the AWS internal network (without any extra configuration required).
Maybe I am missing something here ?

Comment: My comment about the S3 endpoint not overriding the public url was wrong, I've deleted the comment. I apologize for the misinformation, I have updated the answer with the actual answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the update it was exactly what I wasn't understanding. Thank you ! (and sorry for my initial question / post which wasn't very clear I admit)